# Add the Date and Time in the same var

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two fields, one gets the date, the other the hour and minutes, but I want to save the two values in a variable in the format: 0000-00-00T00: 00: 00.000Z, how can I do?

component.html

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                <mat-label>Fecha Inicio</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Date"
                [matDatepicker]="DatePicker"
                name="date"
                formControlName="date" readonly required>
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="DatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #DatePicker
                startView="multi-year"
                (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, DatePicker)"></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pl-sm-8 no-errors-spacer" fxFlex="50">
                <mat-label>Hora:</mat-label>
                <input matInput
                type="time"
                formControlName="time" required>
            </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
  createComposeForm(): FormGroup
  {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      date: [''],
      time: [''],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.form = this.createComposeForm();
    let date= this.form.get('date').value.toISOString()
    let time= this.form.get('time').value
   }
```

14:52

Comment: concate both the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to make a function for getting full date-time from the time like this**

```
getFormattedDateFromTime(time) {
    var timeParts = time.split(":");
    var startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setHours(+timeParts[0]);
    startDate.setMinutes(+timeParts[1]);
    startDate.setSeconds(0);
    var options = {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "long",
      day: "numeric",
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      second: "numeric",
      timeZoneName: "short"
    };
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", options).format(startDate);
  }
```

After that, you need to pass your form value to this function and do concate like this

```
const date = this.form.get("date").value.toISOString();
const time = this.getFormattedDateFromTime(this.form.get("time").value);
const myDate = new Date(time).toISOString();
const dateOnly = datTime.split("T");
const timeOnly = myDate.split("T");
const finalDateTime = `${dateOnly[0]}T${timeOnly[1]}`;
console.log("datTime::", finalDateTime);
```

**I have attached [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-5zrcem?file=app/datepicker-overview-example/datepicker-overview-example.component.ts) demo so you can get idea please look this:**

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-5zrcem?file=app/datepicker-overview-example/datepicker-overview-example.component.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var day = '03/24/2020';
var time = '10:06 am';

function combineDateTime(date, time)
{
 var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
 var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
 var ampm = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
 if(ampm == "pm" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
 if(ampm == "am" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
 var Hours = hours.toString();
 var Minutes = minutes.toString();
 if(hours<10) Hours = "0" + Hours;
 if(minutes<10) Minutes = "0" + Minutes;
 time = Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":00";
 var d = new Date(day);
 var n = d.toISOString().substring(0,10);
 var combinedDate = new Date(n+"T"+time);
 return combinedDate;
 }

 alert(combineDateTime(day,time).toISOString());
```